# Can't use import with package_as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4, flascc

For some reason, when I use `package_as3` in FlasCC I can't import any classes to use as a `var`.

```
package_as3
(
    "#package private\n"
    "import flash.system.MessageChannel;\n"
    "var mc:MessageChannel;\n"
);
```

When I try to build anything that has this code in it, I get this:

```
Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MessageChannel.
```

whenever I use the compiled SWC in Flex.

EDIT:

This doesn't just apply to `flash.system.MessageChannel`; it seems to happen to anything that gets imported.

Answer (score 0):

## A few things to try out

### Syntax

I don't think you are supposed to wrap each line in quotes, nor add \n for string termination, so that's one thing that need mending.

### SDK

The MessageChannel class requires SDK version 4.6 and above so did you select the correct SDK and add it to your buildpath?

### Runtime

Also the MessageChannel interface did not get run-time support until version 14.0.0 (AIR or Player), so in project properties -> ActionScript Compiler, did you set the 'Require Flash Player Version' to version 14.0 or above?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact that you were using FlasCC, not just Flex. Still, I will leave the answer up in-case there is anything there that will put you on the right track.